# How to change the size of images within the hyperlink part of a <a href""></a> tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

i have a image gallery where a small version of an image can be seen on the page. When the user clicks on the image, some jquery code is executed which will show the original image (like an image gallery). In order to do this, each image has a hyperlink to echo the original file. The code works fine, however some of the original images are really big and often extend down the page. Here is the code:

```
<div id="w">
  <div id="content">
      <div id="thumbnails"><?php while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){?>
        <a href="<img src="<?php echo $row["Image"]; ?>"/>"><img src="<?php echo $row["Image"]; ?>" height="124.4" width="124.4" border="5" alt="turntable" /></a>
        <?php } ?>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#thumbnails a').lightBox();
});
</script>
```

As you can see, within the hyperlink tags i have (). As i said before, some of the original images are really big.

Does anyone know how to ensure that when the "original image" is shown, that the image size stays within the actual page size?

I've played around with it, i copied the  tags into the hyperlink and tried to change the size. But it doesn't work.

Comment: well, you could use some CSS on the image, like `max-width: 100%;` (same for `max-height`). But if you're linking directly to the raw image (with no HTML,CSS, etc. involved), it's up to the browser to decide what to do with it, and you can't really do anything. Except return a smaller image...

Comment: or do it in a fixed <img style="width:100px;height:100px" /> or whatever dimensions you want

Comment: just set `max-height` and `max-width` attributes 100% to your container.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change image Size from `<a href=""></a>` But within you image HTML code you can set attribute of Width and Height.

```
<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing which lightbox you're using it's tough to give you a good answer, a good answer being limiting the size of the image in the lightbox itself.

A better answer is for you to upload images at a particular size, any in browser resizing of an image is going to have a degraded look plus you're still downloading a bigger image so you're wasting bandwidth and load time.

That being said you can limit an image by simply setting the CSS of the img element. Percentages will only work if the image is contained in an element that has a size applied so use pixels.

```
img{
     max-width:500px;
}
```

You could also set max-height if you want, I'd only set one or the other though to ensure images don't get distorted.

Answer (score -1):

Hard to test without the proper rnvironment but have you tried the following:

```
<a href="<img src="<?php echo $row["Image"]; ?>"/>">
    <img src="<?php echo $row["Image"]; ?>" height="124.4" width="124.4" border="5" alt="turntable" />
</a>
```

replace with and adjust the percentage accordingly to the size that sits the best

```
<a href="<img style="width="100%" src="<?php echo $row["Image"]; ?>"/>">
    <img src="<?php echo $row["Image"]; ?>" height="124.4" width="124.4"  border="5" alt="turntable" />
</a>
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. The OP wanted to know how to limit the site of the *original* image, not the size of the thumbnail.

Comment: I didn't relize that was the thumbnail. Like I said, hard to test without an environment. But the fundamental idea still works. So I edited my answer to apply the width to the correct element